# Replace a range of numbers by listing them in a row using Asnible

Tags: ansible

I`m trying to parse semi-structured text (EXOS config) with module ansible.netcommon.cli_parse and everything is going well except bringing the port ranges to a linear display.

Below is an examples:
This:

```
        "MGMT-vlan": {
            "ports": {
                "tagged": "2,7-8,13,16-18,30,36,42,57"
```

I wanna convert to:

```
        "MGMT-vlan": {
            "ports": {
                "tagged": "2,7,8,13,16,17,18,30,36,42,57"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of a Python function that does range expansion like that.

```
def expand_ranges(s):
    for atom in s.split(","):
        if "-" in atom:
            a, _, b = atom.partition("-")
            yield from range(int(a), int(b) + 1)
        else:
            yield int(atom)


expanded_ports = list(expand_ranges("2,7-8,13,16-18,30,36,42,57"))
print(expanded_ports)
```

This prints out

```
[2, 7, 8, 13, 16, 17, 18, 30, 36, 42, 57]
```

You could then wrap this in e.g. [an Ansible filter function library](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins).

This could possibly be enough (my Ansible is rather rusty these days):

```
def expand_ports(value):
    return ",".join(expand_ranges(value))


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'expand_ports': expand_ports,
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems this solution is more suitable for my case

Answer (score 0):

Given the parsed data

```yaml
    config:
      k1: conf1
      MGMT-vlan:
        ports:
          tagged: "2,7-8,13,16-18,30,36,42,57"
      k9: conf9
```

It's possible to create the sequence

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        seq: "{{ seq|d([]) + [_seq] }}"
      loop: "{{ config['MGMT-vlan'].ports.tagged.split(',') }}"
      vars:
        _arr: "{{ item.split('-') }}"
        _seq: "{{ range(_arr.0|int, _arr.1|d(_arr.0)|int + 1)|join(',') }}"
    - debug:
        var: seq|join(',')
```

gives

```yaml
  seq|join(','): 2,7,8,13,16,17,18,30,36,42,57
```

Now, combine the data

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        config: "{{ config|combine({'MGMT-vlan':
                                   {'ports':
                                   {'tagged': seq|join(',')}}}) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  config:
    MGMT-vlan:
      ports:
        tagged: 2,7,8,13,16,17,18,30,36,42,57
    k1: conf1
    k9: conf9
```